# Creating Face from 4 Vertex Points making Triangle Instead?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, faces

I am following this tutorial and every time I click the same 4 vertex points as in the video is creates a triangle instead of the face like in the video.

Here's my model

[image]

[image]

But in the video I am watching he does this and makes it like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you're working under a *Mirror* modifier(?), in which case the vertices you're trying to bridge to with <kbd>F</kbd> do not exist in the editable mesh.

Has your tutor applied the modifier?

Or maybe the tutor has <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> extruded the edge orthogonally to the mirror-axis, with 'Bisect' checked for that axis?